# Interactive batch file to run psexec to run ninite install on remote computer

Tags: batch-file, installation, psexec

I'd like to make a batch file for use at our help desk that, when ran, will prompt the user to enter a computer name then run `psexec` that will use their input to identify the remote computer to run a `ninite` installer on. I'm pretty new to IT and to StackOverflow so let me know if I'm not being clear or expressing things correctly.

Here is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
@echo off
echo "enter machine"
set /p machine=
psexec \\%machine% -s -u \\myserver\Installdir\NiniteTest\NiniteQuickTime.exe
pause
```

What I want it to do is use `psexec` to run the `ninite` installer on a remote computer where the user doesn't have to interact with it and whoever is at the help desk and executes the batch from the help desk computer can just enter the computer name of the the remote computer and their admin credentials.